# Table View not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I already completed my app coding in xcode 4 but i am trying on this code on xcode 5 many problem occured in UITableview. table lines and content of the table are not visible. Normally table is display correctly but i am set horizontal and separator lines for  subview in tableview that time frame only set lines and content not visible.

In picture i am set background color for tableview in blue color so here content area appear only in white color

```
{
        UIView *subView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 510, ([subViewsDataArr count] * 50) + 10)];
        subView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        subView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        subView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        subView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
        [myCell addSubview:subView];

        int y = 5;
        for (int j=0; j<[subViewsDataArr count]; j++, y = y+50) {
            UIView *cellView =[[UIView alloc] init];
            cellView.frame =CGRectMake(5, y, 500, 50);
            cellView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
            [subView addSubview:cellView];

            if (j == 0)
            {
                int x =-1;

                UIImageView *horizontalLineImgStart =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 1)];
                horizontalLineImgStart.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"horizontalLine.png"];
                [cellView addSubview:horizontalLineImgStart];

                UIImageView *seperatorLineImgStart =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 1, 50)];
                seperatorLineImgStart.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperatorLine.png"];
                [cellView addSubview:seperatorLineImgStart];

                for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {

                    UILabel *cellLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                    [cellLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[subViewsDataArr objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i]]];
                    cellLbl.textAlignment =UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 7) {
                        cellLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:12];
                        cellLbl.numberOfLines =2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cellLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth =YES;
                        cellLbl.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:10];
                    }
                    [cellLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    cellLbl.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
                    [cellView addSubview:cellLbl];


                    UIImageView *seperatorLineImg =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
                    if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 5)
                    {
                        cellLbl.frame = CGRectMake(x + 1, 5, 55, 40);
                        seperatorLineImg.frame =CGRectMake(x + 55, 0, 1, 50);
                        x = x + 55;
                    }
                    else if (i == 6 || i == 7)
                    {
                        cellLbl.frame = CGRectMake(x + 1, 5, 80, 40);
                        seperatorLineImg.frame =CGRectMake(x + 80, 0, 1, 50);
                        x = x + 80;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cellLbl.frame = CGRectMake(x + 1, 5, 60, 40);
                        seperatorLineImg.frame =CGRectMake(x + 60, 0, 1, 50);
                        x = x + 60;
                    }
                    seperatorLineImg.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperatorLine.png"];
                    [cellView addSubview:seperatorLineImg];

                }

                UIImageView *horizontalLineImgEnd =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 500, 1)];
                horizontalLineImgEnd.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"horizontalLine.png"];
                [cellView addSubview:horizontalLineImgEnd];
            }
            else
            {
                int x =-1;

                UIImageView *horizontalLineImgStart =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 1)];
                horizontalLineImgStart.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"horizontalLine.png"];
                [cellView addSubview:horizontalLineImgStart];

                UIImageView *seperatorLineImgStart =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 1, 50)];
                seperatorLineImgStart.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperatorLine.png"];
                [cellView addSubview:seperatorLineImgStart];

            for (int i=0; i < 8; i++ , txtFldTagVal= txtFldTagVal + 1) {

                    UITextField *cellTxtFld = [[UITextField alloc] init];
                    cellTxtFld.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[subViewsDataArr objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i]];
                    cellTxtFld.textAlignment =UITextAlignmentCenter;
                    cellTxtFld.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:12];
                    [cellTxtFld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    cellTxtFld.textColor =[UIColor brownColor];
                    cellTxtFld.tag =5000 + txtFldTagVal;
                    cellTxtFld.delegate =self;
                    cellTxtFld.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                    [cellView addSubview:cellTxtFld];

                    UIImageView *seperatorLineImg =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
                    if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 5)
                    {
                        cellTxtFld.frame = CGRectMake(x + 1, 5, 55, 40);
                        seperatorLineImg.frame =CGRectMake(x + 55, 0, 1, 50);
                        x = x + 55;
                    }
                    else if (i == 6 || i == 7)
                    {
                        cellTxtFld.frame = CGRectMake(x + 1, 5, 80, 40);
                        seperatorLineImg.frame =CGRectMake(x + 80, 0, 1, 50);
                        x = x + 80;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cellTxtFld.frame = CGRectMake(x + 1, 5, 60, 40);
                        seperatorLineImg.frame =CGRectMake(x + 60, 0, 1, 50);
                        x = x + 60;
                    }
                    seperatorLineImg.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperatorLine.png"];
                    [cellView addSubview:seperatorLineImg];
                }

                UIImageView *horizontalLineImgEnd =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 500, 1)];
                horizontalLineImgEnd.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"horizontalLine.png"];
                [cellView addSubview:horizontalLineImgEnd];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain your query clearly with some reference then only you should get any help here.

Comment: i am create table view with horizondal and separator line images ,that time table frame added nothing visible.

Comment: if i am set subview in table view that time only table view not visible.

Comment: @user3030120 : can you please write clear queries, i am not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you add something in table cell like removeFromSuperView so that only that view is not visible please remove following code if that there in your code

[myCell.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[myCell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

Comment: ya correct now the problem is solved.but once i remove subview it merge another subview